# посоветуйте гайд или книгу по администрированию Win 10/8

Tags: windows, книги, администрирование

Друзья, пришел работать в компанию аналитиком, и по совместительству немного возится с парком техники.  Т.к опыта в администрировании нет совсем, прошу помощи в поиске толкового гайда или книги по настройке пользовательских машин, прав доступа и тд. Возможно встречали статью "Что в первую очередь стоит сделать админу"

Вариант "книги не помогут, нужна практика" не рассматриваю, т.к без знаний и практики не может быть.

Интересующие области:
Настройка прав доступа.
Что-то общее про IP телефонию.
Настройка фаервола.
Резервное копирование.

контора из себя представляет 13 компов под win10, одна из них "сервер" обычная винда с общим доступом к папке. Сейчас параллельно пытаюсь писать документацию, описание сети, собираю пароли и явки, удаляю ПО и тд. Хочется все настроить, чтобы все работало, и не переживать, что кто-то хакнет или юзер на устанавливает амиго всякие.

Comment: Я бы начал с создания образа ОС, в котором натыкал бы софта, создал бы 2-х пользователей (если нет AD): с полными правами и с ограниченными, собрал бы инфу о железе, качнул под это дрова И СНЁС БЫ ВСЁ К ХРЕНАМ. Ну с сохраненеием пользовательских файлов конечно. Опыт показывает, что чистить уже существующие машины - адский и неблагодарный гемморой. Да, заранее надо узнать какой специфичный софт используется. Типа 1с, криптопро и т.д. А то может получиться весело.

Comment: как вы храните образы ОС? На ноутах обычно есть "recovery",но мой опыт подсказывает, что его можно похерить (Шифровальщик, например). Правильно ли я понял, что можно создать дистребутив винды с пакетом программ, которые сами установятся? Можно ссылка про такое чудо?

Comment: Я храню в формате проекта `clonezilla`. И разворачиваю ей же. Удобно, бесплатно, переносимо. Будут интересны подробности - напиши мне в жаббер. Просто тут рассказывать - байт не хватит. Тема очень обширная.

Comment: Ты жив? Я ответил в жаббер. Маякни.

Answer (score 1):

Я админ, 8 лет опыта.

Книга не нужна.

Бекапы

```
(для начала простой zip архив по расписанию или вручную по надобности)
```

1. представте что комп/роутер/.. украли, что нужно с него для работы то и нужно бекапить.
2. сделайте бэкапы на **внешний**(!) носитель и **отключите его**(!).
3. проверте бекапы
4. восстанови пару машин/папок/роутеров/.. из бекапов
5. добавьте в бекапы то что забыли туда добавить.

Права:

1. Выставьте всем права до Обычный пользователь.
2. Тем кто начнет возмущаться - рассмотрите ситуацию лично, скорее всего права не нужны.

Firewall

1. Начните читать про настройку Kerio WinRoute Firewall [любой мануал с примерами](https://clck.ru/BHYrG)
2. Если у вас сервер на винде смотрит наружу - никакой фаервол вас ни спасет (лучше проверьте бекапы)

Уход за компами

1. на каждой машине запустить [ADW cleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/) удалит вирусы/трояны/рекламу
2. [COMODO* Antivirus](http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=5&topic=48985) версия 8 (10 задает много вопросов, скоро починят)

   ---

*COMODO бесплатен для **КОММЕРЧЕСКОГО** использования

1 раз в год лучше в марте/апреле (к августовской жаре всё перегреется и сгорит)

1. Разбирайте компы старше 1 года, пылесосте заменяйте термопасту(не на КПТ8 / Алсил3) на процессорах и видеокартах.
2. проверяйте [вздувшиеся конденсаторы](https://clck.ru/BHYst) на платах
3. проверяйте [блоки питания на нагрузку](http://vsbot.ru/pomoshty-zhelezu/kak-bystro-proverit-computernyi-blok-pitaniya.html)
4. Никогда не смазывайте вентиляторы - меняйте на новые нормальных производителей.

Comment: Чем `кпт8` не угодил?

Comment: @donRumata Теплопроводностью 65,8 Вт/м*К при 100ᵒ (вместо 10+) Рабочий интервал температур: до +180 °C (я использую только 300+)

Comment: @donRumata КПТ Обладает критическим недостатком при высыхании из теплопроводника превращается в теплоизолятор. Особенно от нее горят ноутбуки с малой поверхностью чипов и слабыми + забытыми пылью радиаторами. Ремонт же после такой "экономии" обходится от $40 работа по BGA пайке чипа + сам чип от $60. КПТ-8 создана в 1980-ых годах для применения на транзисторах, диодах, стабилизаторах и прочих узлах РЭА на современные горячие чипы она подходит никак, на "распилы" и селероны можно мазать всё от КПТ до зубной пасты.

Comment: Был бы у меня такой наставкик, я может быть и не женился)

Про бэкапы. Как реализовать копирование данных с пользовательских машин? Копируем на удаленный диск, потом с него делаем бэк ап на внешний диск? Прекрасно понимаю, что копирование в облако и т.д - не панацея, в что подключено к сети может быть зашифровано/украдено. Верно? Раз в неделю актуально или нужно чаще?

Comment: Про права. Поставил всем пользователя, но думал прям запретить исполнение любых файлов без ввода пароля (Исключение white list), чтобы например шифровальщики ( Аля ваннакрипт) не нагадили.

Антивирусу - куплен касперский под винду. Сейчас появятся две машины на ubuntu, стоит там беспокоится?

Comment: Про файр волл. Сейчас для защиты используется только OpenDNS поднятый на роутере. Что значит смотрит в наружу? Это обычный пк руководителя, на нем общая папка, там база 1с и файлопомойка

Comment: @lion295 жениться всё-же рекомендую! = чистый дом + еда + любовь-морковь... по сути: копировать на сьёмный носитель(внешний HDD) либо на linux машину которая сама пробежит по сетевым папкам и соберет то что надо(если на ней открыть сетевую папку то ее например зашифрует шифровальщик.) Частота это зависит (it depends...) от ваших данных какой период вам не страшно потерять час/день/неделю/месяц? у меня всё копировалось при включении компа 1-15 минут сотрудники привыкли. + у всех ярлычек был для ручного копирования.

Comment: @lion295 про права: исполнение файлов по white list я в это не верю, но пробуйте. от шифровальщиков так не защититься они по дырам в винде ходят вроде, Касперский тоже не мой выбор - промолчу. ubuntu единственный совет: не сидеть из под рута и не шарить папочки для доступа из под винды(шифровальщики шифранут)

Comment: @lion295 Фаервол: OpenVPN  я так и не поднял, здорово что у вас есть. попробуйте между "сервером 1с+помойка" и интернетом затолкать машинку на linux  или машинку c kerio (есть еще микротики, поизучайте если время будет) так у вас винда не дубет в интернет торчать меньше гадости соберёте. т.е будет  |машины|-|роутер|-|1c+помойка|-|linux/kerio|-|ИНТЕРНЕТ|

Comment: @Jiraff537 эм. не совсем понял со схемой. Сейчас выглядит так: Интернет-роутер-свич-машины. Как может роутер стоять после 1с помойки?) И про линукс. Есть на линукс нет расшареных, а только он по винде ходит, проблем не будет? не дотянется?

Comment: по схеме: тогда к вашей схеме можно добавить linux-машину: "Интернет-<сюда_Linux>-роутер-свич-машины" по линуксу: (не совсем понял ваши вопросы) но суть сводится к простому: linux с легкостью ходит по папкам расшаренным из под винды. Все папки расшаренные на linux-машине доступные из под винды могут быть зашифрованы/повреждены вирусами(поэтому лучше на linux-машине папки не расшаривать).

Answer (score 0):

Я знания только практикой получал: сам создавал себе проблемы, порой серьезные и сам пытался решить их. не видел ни одной нормальной небольшой и легкой книги, где бы было собрана нормальная инфа по настройке,  в основном для каких-то супер-лузеров видел, например: снизу слева есть кнопка пуск- она оч важная.
Если уж очень хочется литературы, порекомендовал бы серию книг Таненбаума(чтиво серьезное)

[Современные операционные системы](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5144889/)

[Компьютерные сети](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1504328/)

[Архитектура компьютера](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/20032936/)

Comment: на всех форумах пишут - я все через практику познал! Пытался читать документацию MS, но хватая на 5 минут, слишком  муторно написано. Спасибо, посмотрю что там пишут в серьёзных книжках

Comment: я так думаю, есть смысл что-то читать, если есть какая-нибудь конкретная проблема и по ней уже искать решение

Comment: @lion295 документацию M$ советуйте читать только врагам. ))